# Are the points that make the function f(x) non-differentiable the same as the points that make the derivative function f '(x) undefined?

Tags: derivatives

Are the points that make the function f(x) non-differentiable the same as the points that make the derivative function f '(x) undefined? If yes, then what is the point from giving a more complex formula for differentiability (to check if tangent exists) at some value, i.e. we can easily find f '(x) and find the values that make it undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> we can easily find $f '(x)$

By definition if $f : A \subset \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, then for any $x 
\in A$ we define
$$f'(x) := \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
whenever the right hand side exists. Thus finding $f'$ and the tangent limits are *logically* equivalent. Take an extreme example,
$$
f(x) = \cases{\frac{1}{q} \text{ if $x = \frac{p}{q}$ is rational with $p$ and $q$ coprime}\\ 0 \text{$\ $ if $x$ is irrational}}
$$

also know as [Thomae's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function). It is hard to see whether $f$ is continuous just from taking a look at the definition, let alone computing $f'$ whenever possible.

> As it turns out, $f$ is only continuous at irrational values, but differentiable **nowhere**. The Wikipedia link contains both proofs, or so it claims.

Comment: Also, by considering the Thomae function raised to the $r$'th power for $r>2,$ we get a function with the same points of continuity that is differentiable on a set having Hausdorff dimension $1 - \frac{2}{r}$ in every nonempty open interval and not differentiable on a set having Hausdorff dimension $\frac{2}{r}$ in every nonempty open interval. Note that the Hausdorff dimension statement is strictly stronger than saying "uncountably many points in every nonempty open interval". For more details, see this [13 December 2006 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=5432910).